# C# BitConverter.ToInt64 - Destination array is not long enough

Tags: c#

I am running into issues when I execute the following C# code

```
byte[] addr = new byte[IntPtr.Size];
IntPtr conv = (IntPtr)(BitConverter.ToInt64(addr, 0));
```

The error I am getting is:

```
System.ArgumentException: Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection. Check array index and length.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.BitConverter.ToInt64(Byte[] value, Int32 startIndex)
```

I am still pretty much a noob in C# so learn as I go... Do you have an idea what I am missing here? I understand there appears to be an issue with the destination array, but not really sure why... Any guidance highly appreciated.

Comment: not only for C#, but C too.

Comment: Your code is running as 32 bits, so IntPtr.Size is 4, but an Int64 requires 8 bytes.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You assign `nRead` but never use the value...

Comment: Apologies, removed: "IntPtr nRead = IntPtr.Zero;" as not related to the issue. It is being later used in ReadProcessMemory call and not related to the issue.

Comment: `IntPtr conv = (IntPtr)(Environment.Is64BitProcess ? BitConverter.ToInt64(addr, 0) : BitConverter.ToInt32(addr, 0));
`

Answer (score 3):

The underlying error here is that the *source* array is 4 bytes long and to read an Int64 it needs to read 8 bytes.

The oddity is that you get an error about a *destination* array. The method you call shouldn't be copying anything to any arrays, so why is it talking about a destination?

The error messages in the source use a mechanism where the error is identified by an id, in this case [Arg_ArrayPlusOffTooSmall](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/bitconverter.cs,681f6fa6df99de55,references).

It seems reasonable to use such an id as the name of the id matches the error.

However, most of the uses of [Arg_ArrayPlusOffTooSmall](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/throwhelper.cs,dcda312259ea549f,references) are when the array is used as the destination of a write rather than as the source of a read, so the error message is incorrectly made more 'helpful' by adding details which are incorrect in this case.

Congratulations, you've found a bug in .net!

Comment: Indeed the "bitness" of the file compiled file was causing issue. Rookie mistake. Many thanks!